# Input Group Addon with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I get an input group addon added to this div here? I've tried a few things but I can't get a dollar sign input group to display on the same line with the text_field_tag text box.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag :starting_bet %>:
    <%= text_field_tag 'bet[starting_bet]', nil, placeholder: '10' %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= label_tag :starting_bet %>:
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
    <%= text_field_tag 'bet[starting_bet]', nil, placeholder: '10' %>
  </div>
</div>
```